# Importing a common library into a Vue SPA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-modules

Having a hard time trying to understand what I imagine should be a simple task, but am prepared to accept that maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way and willing to change my plan into the proper way.

In short I have a .js file which contains hundreds of objects and functions that are used in our applications.  We're modernising our approach and refactoring some of the functions.

As a very basic example I have:

```
**COMMON.JS**
const dynamicYearColumn= {
    resizable: false, suppressMovable: true, sortable: true, width: 100, menuTabs: [], type: 'numericColumn',
}


const defaultPercentageColumn= {

    resizable: false, suppressMovable: true, sortable: true, width: 150, menuTabs: [], type: 'numericColumn',
    //comparator: customPercentageCompare,
    valueFormatter: formatPercent,
    cellStyle: { 'text-align': 'right' },
    cellClass: function (params) { var className = numberToColorClass(params.value); return className }
}


function formatPercent(number) {

    if (isNaN(number.value) == true) { return '-' }
    return isFinite(numberWithCommas(parseFloat(number.value, 2).toFixed(this.defaultDecimalRounding))) ? numberWithCommas(parseFloat(number.value, 2).toFixed(this.defaultDecimalRounding)) + '%' : '?';
}

function numberWithCommas(n) {
    var parts = n.toString().split("."); return parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
}
```

Within my main.js, I now have:

```
import common from './scripts/common.js'
const commonLibrary = {
    install() {
        Vue.common = common
        Vue.prototype.$common = common
    }
}

Vue.use(commonLibrary)
```

And this is where I'm failing to succeed.

In my common.js, if I enclose the code within `export default` I have to change the code (removing the const's so the objects are actual object definitions, and `formatPercent` is then unrecognised.

If I `export {dynamicYearColumn,defaultPercentageColumn}` then that 'kinda' works, but I still get undefined on formatPercent and numberWithCommas.

Likewise if I try the create a Mixin, then this too works, but any functions within the Mixins methods are unrecognised PLUS I've been advised not to push such a large library into Mixins as this isn't very good practice.

I appreciate there's an abundance of sources out there with good examples, but to be honest I can't really think of the correct terminology to even start looking for working examples.

TLDR;

I simply want to allow access to a large collection of objects and functions from a single JS file and called from my Vue SPA on any component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're almost there.

Let's assume that you want to do this:

```js
import common from './scripts/common.js'
```

To achieve this we need `common.js` to have a `default` export. So something starting `export default`.

Further, let's assume we want to access the objects and functions as `common.dynamicYearColumn`, `common.formatPercent`, etc.. Even ignoring the `import`/`export` part this implies that `common` needs to be an object with properties called `dynamicYearColumn`, `formatPercent`, etc.. Some of those properties will be functions but that doesn't really make much difference.

So let's briefly consider how we could build such an object.

```js
const common = {}
common.dynamicYearColumn = { /* object properties here */ }
common.formatPercent = function (number) { /* implementation here */ }
```

Of course object literals allow us to define the object with these properties straightaway, rather than adding them later:

```js
const common = {
  dynamicYearColumn: { /* object properties here */ },
  formatPercent: function (number) { /* implementation here */ }
}
```

ES6 added some syntactic sugar to simplify the creation of functions within an object, so this can be reduced down to:

```js
const common = {
  dynamicYearColumn: { /* object properties here */ },
  formatPercent (number) { /* implementation here */ }
}
```

This is the object that we want to create within `common.js` and then export. Putting it all together we get:

```js
export default {
  dynamicYearColumn: {
    // ...  
  },

  defaultPercentageColumn: {
    // ...
  },

  formatPercent (number) {
    // ...
  },

  numberWithCommas (n) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Adding them to the `Vue.prototype`, as you are in your example, will make them available within your component as:

```js
this.$common.formatPercent(25)
```

In your templates it would be:

```html
{{ $common.formatPercent(25) }}
```

This is all good but note that you won't be able to use the functions as filters. So you can't write this:

```html
{{ 25 | $common.formatPercent }}
```

If that's something you want then you'll have to register those functions as filters within your plugin.